# Limit CUPS printer discovery from multiple interfaces

Tags: networking, cups

ServerFault! Coming here right from StackOverflow :)

Here is the problem: I have a Xubuntu PC that has two physical network interfaces. One of them is for purposes of my working room, another is to connect to other rooms in a building.

CUPS detects every single damn printer there is in a whole building. At least, those that are somehow ended up in that network. How do I make CUPS NOT to scan this external interface for printers? It should be up all the time.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a configuration in [cups-browsed.conf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/cups-browsed.conf.5.html) to deny printers of your "external" interface, e.g.:

```
# forbid browsing of external network
BrowseDeny 192.168.3.0/24
```

or

```
# forbid all,
BrowseDeny All

# then allow your local printers
BrowseAllow 192.168.7.20
BrowseAllow 192.168.7.21
```

Also have a look at the `BrowseFilter` options.

Comment: Worked marvellous! Thanks! Accepted and +1'd.